# Use boost::asio without linking to OpenSSL

Tags: c++, boost, openssl

I'm working on a project that uses boost::asio. By default it links with OpenSSL libraries, however no SSL features are used. I need to get rid of OpenSSL dependencies, is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Why do you *have to* get rid of it? Just convenience? The *easy* option would be to just bite the bullet; link with (and ship) OpenSSL - you don't use it, so it's a little "un-tidy" and a few extra bytes on the disk of the user, but there's no harm done..

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense as the OpenSSL part of boost asio is optional.  i.e. it only links in openssl when you use it.

Also by default boost asio is header only.  So you must have gone out of your way to compile the library version WITH openssl included.

You can read about it [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html).

If you want to only include openssl when you use it, then I would just use the default header only version and you will only get what you use and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Compile boost yourself and remove the OpenSSL bits first. Would be "a way to do it".

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because other projects depend on it. Any other options (maybe some define etc)?